# Python nose throws TypeError error with coverage

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py, python-coverage

When I am using the nosetests 1.2.1 with coverage, it throws the below error.

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tw/core/view.py:223: DeprecationWarning: object.__new__() takes no parameters
obj = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/nosetests", line 9, in <module>
  load_entry_point('nose==1.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'nosetests')()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 118, in __init__
**extra_args)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/unittest.py", line 815, in __init__
  self.parseArgs(argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/core.py", line 135, in parseArgs
  self.config.configure(argv, doc=self.usage())
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/config.py", line 338, in configure
  self.plugins.configure(options, self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 284, in configure
  cfg(options, config)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 99, in __call__
  return self.call(*arg, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py", line 167, in simple
  result = meth(*arg, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/plugins/cover.py", line 137, in configure
  branch=self.coverBranches, data_suffix=None)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'branch'
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the coverage part. What version of `coverage` do you have ? If it's too old, it may not support branch coverage, thus rejecting the `branch` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the last version of nose but an old version of coverage, and nose uses features recently added in coverage.

Branch coverage support was added in `coverage` 3.2, and you have the version 3.0.1 (see https://crate.io/packages/coverage/).

You need to update coverage.

- If you installed it manually, `pip install -U coverage` should do the trick.
- If you installed if from your distro's repository, you should forward this to them so they fix it. In the meantime, you can either update it globally with `sudo pip install -U coverage` or use a virtualenv.